# Can I use calculus to calculate how fast a the cracker of a whip is moving when it cracks?

Tags: acoustics, calculus, models, shock-waves

So I know that when a whip cracks it is breaking the sound barrier and makes a sonic boom. I understand that this is
Because of conservation of momentum as the whip tapers in thickness and hairpins at the last second. Is there a way I could use calculus to model this effect and calculate exactly how fast the tip if the whip is going?

Comment: When you say "use calculus" to model it, what exactly do you mean? Pretty much everything in the universe is modeled using derivatives and integrals, so I suspect you have something slightly narrower in mind.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to model how tapering of a whip effects the speed of the the end of the whip. I just assumed that it would require calculus. My end goal is better understanding the physics involved, and to be able to calculate how fast the end of the whip is going when it cracks. I have done 1 1/2 years of calculus so far and I feel like I should be able to figure this out.

Comment: "Could you ?" Well maybe not. It turns out the cause of the supersonic boom and maths to model it are rather detailed.  If you are interested here is [a link to a paper](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/tmcmillen/papers/WhipWaves2003.pdf) (34 pages !) detailing one model for this process.